# How to secure memcached on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: security, memcached, ubuntu-12.04

Running memcached on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

My /etc/memcached.conf file is set to only listen to localhost.
i.e. -l 127.0.0.1

But I can still telnet through to it from the outside even though it is set to only listen to localhost. My site really doesn't host any sensitive data whatsoever but I am a bit stumped that the config file doesn't really seem to do its job. I don't really see the need for IPtables. Any easy fix to secure memcached without having to set up IPtables?

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart the service, you might have made change without restarting
2. To make more secure do not use the standard port